# Проблема с SEO посоветуйте что делать

Tags: wordpress, seo

У меня проблема с сео, на сайте вордпресс, я уже делал все, что только смог найти и уже не знаю, что делать, сайт просто не отображается в поисковой выдаче даже если ввести точное название, а только если ввести полный адрес: перевізник.com.ua  возможно это проблема с тем что деменное имя по украински?  Подскажите пожалуйста что делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш веб сайт представляет бизнес инфо, т.е. это бизнес, но не имеет полной и легко проверяемой инфо о организации бизнеса и издателя. Для примера проверьте как инфо о бизнесе реализована на веб сайте немецкого издателя **[Шпигель](https://www.spiegel.de/impressum)**. Это явная проблема надежности и достоверности содержания.

Веб сайт имеет логин, но не имеет защищенного соединения HTTPS. Это негативный **[сигнал поискового ранга Гугл](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal)**.

Производительность вебсайта имеет проблемы связанные с Веб Виталс и это есть негативный **[сигнал поискового ранга Гугл](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2021/04/more-details-page-experience)**.

Стартовая страница не имеет описания субъекта содержания. Проще говоря, при открытии страницы не понятна главная тема.

Comment: Пасибо за помощ